# How to stabilise a nation's growth and population despite high birth rate and endemic warfare?

Tags: biology, society

The nation in question is a vast empire with advanced technology slightly beyond modern OECD nations. We will now assume that if something is genetically possible for a healthy human being, they can then engineer and popularize this trait in the new generation of embryos.

So they cannot make Captain America, but can certainly make a generation of olympic atheletes with the intellect of an MIT topper. Without the actual training, of course, just the genetic component.

But the issue is that they are in a constant state of low intensity warfare that periodically flares into wars on the scale of tens of thousands. However, they must still be able to consistently grow in both population and economy, and be able to make use of their vast resources.

How is this possible, if it were possible at all?

Comment: Did you mean to say, "low birth rate"?

Comment: No, I meant high. Overpopulation will be a much bigger problem than lack of workforce. An impoverished and starving populace filled with unemployed young men is not conducive to economic growth.

Comment: If they have a high standard of living their birthrate will fall naturally, having many offspring is not an advantage when they are almost certain to survive to breed. so they need to be using child soldiers if they want a high birthrate.

Comment: (a) The [help] requires that you ask questions that are specific, practical, and answerable without leading to too many answers or intrinsically opinion-based answers. This question is really vague. VTC:ND, happy to retract when you've added details like what you mean by "stable" and specific goals, limitations, and expectations. (b) You have a high birth rate, constant war, and genetic control over your population... what are you asking for exactly? Because controlling your growth appears to be trivial.

Comment: @John: It is not true that high standards of living inevitably produce low birth rates.  Cultural & religious values can produce high birth rates regardless.  I understand there have even been US reality TV shows about (apparently) prosperous people with large numbers of children.  I've even known a few myself.

Comment: @jamesqf the US does not actually have that high of a standard of living, infant mortality in particular is horrible in the US.

Comment: @John: What does infant mortality have to do with the standard of living?  Also consider that the US high infant mortality could be (hypothetically, you understand) due to advanced medicine trying to save extreme premature births, which in other places would go in the statistics as miscarriages.

Comment: @jamesqf standard of living is generally well predicted/measured by three things; infant mortality, female literacy, GDP per capita. there are a few other factors but those three things are generally the most important factors.  The US infant mortality is much higher than that of economically comparable nations because a large portion of the population lack steady access to healthcare. Us infants fare poorly regardless of weight and gestation time https://www.forbes.com/sites/joshuacohen/2021/08/01/us-maternal-and-infant-mortality-more-signs-of-public-health-neglect/?sh=1466787c3a50

Comment: @John: That seems to be a very strange factor to include in standard of living, since it only applies to a small fraction of the population - would-be parents.  I suspect that measure was created in order to give particular results, since it leaves out many important factors, on which the US would score quite high.

Comment: @jamesqf but it doesn't, it affect every aspect of the population.  it basically created the entire population demographic, which affects everything up and down society from age profile to female membership in the workforce, it is also a very good predictor of other things like healthcare quality and access, nutrition, even sanitation.  GDP per capita is actually a fairly weak predictor of the three, since it can be easily skewed if the population has high income disparity.

Comment: @John: But you seem to be tying it to things that have only minor impacts on standard of living.

Comment: @jamesqf but they a huge impacts, otherwise Luxemburg, Qatar, and Singapore would have the highest standards of living on earth, instead most metric pick out places like Norway, Switzerland, or the Netherlands. wealth alone is not enough

Comment: @John: Certainly wealth is not enough.  But what's among the most significant (non political/religious) differences between Qatar & Singapore, versus Norway & Switzerland?  Lots of open space, better climate, and mountains, no?  (FWIW, I've lived in Switzerland and visited Norway.)

Comment: The amount of open space is not that much more than Qatar or Singapore, what there is healthcare, social programs and gender equality  If open space, mountains, and money was enough America would top all the charts. and I'd hardly call their climate better than Singapore's.

Answer (score 0):

More of a frame challenge but also the question needs clarity, imo.

**Your super-war is problematic**

"vast empire with advanced technology slightly beyond modern OECD nations."
"constant state of low intensity warfare that periodically flares into wars on the scale of tens of thousands"

That just conflicts. First those very powerful empires would be nuclear nations. Heck. Even more dangerous stuff might be invented. With that I really doubt they can go to war against each other. Just think of a war between the US and China.
At what point does a country press that big red button with a nuclear symbol on it?

So. You gotta forget direct warfare between both. Last time we had something similar it was WWII and that was not a particularly lovely conflict. In fact I wanna focus on the nuclear attacks since obviously the allies won the war. So. if the victor nuked the already losers. You can bet that the war in your world gonna escalate at some point.

I suggest a proxy war. Like what we have and had and will have again.
Super power A finances small country B to resist the invasion of super power C.
Super power C finances small country D to resist the invasion of super power A.
Or something similar. Extra points when that terribly fails.

**Your normal-war is problematic**

True. It's possible that a super power can go to war directly with a smaller nation. But then what? Again just look at Russia and the whole Crimean thing or the US going to war against Iraq or Afghanistan.

It's not like a super power can't do whatever the heck it wants. I don't want to get into politics and only give example of things happening. Lets leave the morality aside here. Point is that in what world is say Latvia a danger to Russia? Mexico to the US? Tajikistan to China?

True. The super power is not gonna just nuke a country on it's borders or something. But even now super powers can and will crush the opposing army. Install a puppet state. Spy on the other nation. Assassinate, drone strike, buy off...etc opposition. Make military bases. Or just destabilize the other nation to a point that it can no longer offer anything but terrorist attacks or a sort of continues resistance in form of small attacks. Either way super power wins the war pretty quickly.

**Judging by what you said: Both cases your wars don't seem to make sense.**

Maybe there is larger context. So. excuse my ignorance then.

---

**Why super soldiers? Why not better weapons?**

Why you think the near future battle field gonna need more soldiers who are super? If anything super humans gonna void the army. A drone pilot can terrorize a whole town from the comfort of his base.

Heck. Why not mechanized infantry and drone wars. Just imagine. Why would a super power send super humans to fight in a very dirty disgusting battlefield!

I do understand the military does offer a career path and many perks, context. But your average citizen is a giga-Chad. They gonna go do their military with black jack and hookers.

War machines that require little human supervision. Targeted missile attacks from orbital bases. Drones for support. Total battlefield information...etc. I mean this is the future after all.

---

**Captain America?**

Actually I'd say that Captain America is very plausible as a creature. We just don't have the tools..**yet**.

Because from biology we know that it's not impossible for creatures to lift stuff many times over their weight. Others regenerate limbs. Some fly. Some have redundant organs. Some can go as fast as 112 KM/H. Some have skins that is very thick that it might resist small guns. Some can camouflage themselves...etc.

Now the actual combining of all this into a human is never gonna be easy. And I'm pretty sure there will be problems like creating super fast legs but not an upper body so that a test subject gets ripped in half as they accelerate. Or how expending energy, again super fast running is a good example, would require them to gain back the energy or die...etc.

But overall that's kinda possible. It's like how a Dyson sphere or a nuclear powered space ship is possible. We are just not on that level.

---

Not to just be negative. You need a context in which those wars makes sense. Now without knowing more about your world. That's impossible or impractical.

For example if humanity have to fight an alien invasion or monsters from another realm. Or they have to fight an opposing power in another plant or something.

Or maybe the wars are not traditional wars. Rather a sort of testing grounds for the individuals. That explains why every nation expends resource to make the individual such a powerful being. So. It's like an arena.

Comment: That IS true. It is not a war between humans, but I felt that was too much extraneous information. The core thing is that the war exists, and while it's more or less under control it can still go hot every two decades or so. Also, I just used "Captain America" as an example of the sort of impossible things they can't do. Only things we can plausibly see in healthy humans.

Answer (score 0):

**War is good for the economy.**

War consumes lots of materials which must be made, which means jobs.
War means patriotic fervor and scary enemies, so people are more willing to pay tax.

**Tech is good for bloodless wars.**
If you have sweet tech, you can attack the sweet tech of your enemies.  You can kill a lot of people if you want, but if you do tech fighting tech that keeps the humans safe.

**Tech is good for population control.**
Birth control can be accomplished thru tech, as we do.  Encouragement of reproduction can be encouraged through governmental policy.

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly possible for a world to have constant wars and deaths and still manage to have an increasing population. In fact, this is happening all the time. Thousands of people die every single day, but the population is constantly increasing because, despite all the death, there are even more children being born to make up for that.

The crux of this question relies on two things: what is your current population, and what is the net loss of population every year?

Every person dead is a -1 for the population of this world. Every person born is a +1. If the births and deaths are perfectly equal, then regardless of how many people die, your net loss is always 0. That's the interesting thing about population. Even if 10 billion people die every single day, you'd still have a net gain of the population if 80 billion are born every single day. So it's definitely possible to have a horrifying war and still have a population increase. It happens all the time. Even during times of hardship and death, overpopulation can somehow be a major issue at the same time. It's fascinating.

So, to summarize, yes, it's more than possible to have your population grow in a time of war. While the soldiers are dying in droves, the rest of the people just need to have a ton of children.

That's a very basic response, though, so I'll try to go a little more in-depth.

We're assuming that these periodic wars are so bad that even a high birth rate can't keep up with it, correct?

That makes things difficult.

If the wars are completely unavoidable, there are only two ways to fix the problem of the declining population.

Unless cloning (which I am presuming it is not) then the people have to get a little bit creative. They either have to decrease the amount of bloodshed as much as possible, or they need to increase birth rates as much as possible.

The idea of making war less deadly may sound somewhat ridiculous, but it can certainly work.

I am imagining a scenario reminiscent of the Hunger Games. Every time a war comes along, a specific number of troops could be offered up for the sake of the grand battle where the winner takes all. It's a little ridiculous but the idea of two or more small battalions of soldiers facing off in their own mini-war would make for a fascinating plot to almost any story. You might make the battle even smaller by having each side offer a champion of sorts to represent their individual country. The losing side gets to kill the leaders of the opposing faction. The biggest problem with this system would be enforcement. Someone or something would have to stop the opposing warlord from cheating, and getting a tyrant to play by somebody else's rules is nearly impossible.

A war with zero deaths could technically occur, but it would hardly be called a war. Rather than slaughtering each other, the sides could make a complicated game where the loser gets to decide the fate of the winner. This is also a fascinating premise for a story, though I doubt this is what you are trying to achieve.

Introducing the ability to change the genetics of the people makes this far more interesting, though. By changing certain traits and breeding for certain traits, a good enough group of scientists could easily change the world for the better by doing one of several things.

-Make the people of this world more durable and less easy to kill
-Make them capable of producing more children
-Make them require fewer resources to survive
-Make them have a lower propensity for violence.

1 Make them more durable.

By genetically engineering the people of this world to be tougher overall, that would drastically reduce death. I don't just mean physically tougher, I mean tweaking their biology to make them less vulnerable to disease and other health issues, while also making their skin tougher and their bones harder to break. If killing one of these people is hard to do in the first place, surely they will have less of a population decline.

2 Make them capable of producing more children

If the population is on the decline and people are not enthusiastic enough about having kids, then a little bioengineering might be needed to speed up the process. Just have the scientists select people with a high drive to have children and a high capacity to produce children. Maybe certain people are selected to have an unnaturally high birth rate. To make things even more interesting, make these people both stunningly attractive and have ridiculous amounts of hormones that drive people wild. A plot from the perspective of one of these breeders would be interesting. Wouldn't it be lonely to be a government project whose only apparent worth to society is how many people they can seduce and children they can have? That could be an interesting route, though a little disturbing in my opinion.

3 Make them require fewer resources to live.

This is essentially a rehash of my first point. Make the people in such a way that food and water are not as much of a problem. If you can make them so resilient that they don't even need those things anymore, the need for most basic resources like food and drink go out the window. You could even make them so that they no longer desire such things either, even just for the flavor. By making people desireless robots who need and want nothing, they would never take any of the resources, and therefore scarcity would become mostly a thing of the past.

4 Make them have a lower propensity for violence.

If constant wars are a problem, then one way to solve it would be to genetically engineer people to be less violent, or get less pleasure from violence. Selecting for high-empathy, highly passive individuals, would cut down on population loss dramatically. On top of cutting down the rate of wars, it would also make murder and other violent crimes drop dramatically.

Personally, I would incorporate a mixture of all four points. Think about how interesting this would be?

To stop the constant bloodshed from getting worse, the government decides to start a mass genetic engineering project to repair the planet after so much bloodshed.

People are made to be essentially desireless, barely needing things like food or water and basically not wanting them. Any desire for violence is eliminated, making them passive and docile, easy for the rich to control. A subset of the populace is made exceptionally beautiful to seduce the masses and produce more children, also acting as another method of control.

Then we can combine the earlier point. Traditional wars are replaced with complex spectacle sports that pit country against country. No one has a taste for real bloodshed or violence anymore, so they'd rather see it play out in a more interesting game format.

It's your world, so you're free to do as you please. I hope I gave you some interesting ideas, though.